# iOS 8 Handle status bar on xib files not storyboard

Tags: ios, ios8, xib, statusbar, landscape

I have an app that I want to upgrade to iOS 8, but since I found that status bar is being hidden on iPhone in landscape mode, I figured that I need to handle such a behaviour.

I solved this issue on iOS 7 by adding a constraint from the top of the navigation bar to the top of the view ( since I am not using Storyboards, some properties or features are not available through xib like top layout guide ) and used this method:

```
(UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar
{
    return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
}
```

and it was working like charm, but on iOS 8 when status bar is hidden on landscape, navigation bar appears much taller that it is supposed to be. I may handle through constraints and use rotating events, but I believe there must be better ways to handle it.